# XSL tags inside javascript block

Tags: javascript, xslt, scripting

I need my XSL to add dynamic content to a javascript block. I am  wondering if this is possible. Here is an example of what I want to do. The following code does NOT work:

```
<script>
    // Loads the video.
    var s1 = new SWFObject("player-viral.swf","ply","670","350","9","#ffffff");
    s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");
    s1.addParam("allownetworking","all");
    s1.addParam("allowscriptaccess","always");
    s1.addParam("flashvars","file=/Portals/0/<xsl:value-of select="MediaUrlFolder"/><xsl:value-of select="ImageUrlFileName"/>&image=/Portals/0/<xsl:value-of select="ImageUrlFolder"/><xsl:value-of select="ImageUrlFileName"/>");
    s1.write("container");
</script>
```

The parser breaks when I add the XSL value-of tag `<xsl:value-of select="MediaUrlFolder"/>`.

Is there a solution for this? Hi can I add this kind of code in a safe way? Thanks!

=====================================

Now there is a weird problem (that was there before for sure, but I wasn't looking at the source code). The `<script>` block isn't being rendered at all, nothing inside it, not even the `<script></script>` tags. Do you know why this could be happening? Thanks.

Comment: In what way does it "break", does it error? Whats the error?
Does it generate the wrong content?  What content does it generate?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a / between MediaUrlFolder and ImageUrlFileName although perhaps your folders already have a trailing /.  Also you appear to have an unescaped & which should be `&amp`;

I would probably prefer this approach:-

```
<script>
    // Loads the video.
    var mediaUrlFolder = '<xsl:value-of select="MediaUrlFolder"/>'
    var imageUrlFileName = '<xsl:value-of select="ImageUrlFileName"/>'
    var imageUrlFolder = '<xsl:value-of select="ImageUrlFolder"/>'
    var s1 = new SWFObject("player-viral.swf","ply","670","350","9","#ffffff");
    s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");
    s1.addParam("allownetworking","all");
    s1.addParam("allowscriptaccess","always");
    s1.addParam("flashvars","file=/Portals/0/" + mediaUrlFolder  + "/" + imageUrlFileName + "&amp;image=/Portals/0/" + imageUrlFolder + "/" + imageUrlFileName);
    s1.write("container");
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I will try this. Regarding your first question, yes, the folder variable already holds the last folder slash so the URL should be OK. Thks.

Comment: Now there is a weird problem (that was there before for sure, but I wasn't looking at the source code). The <script> block isn't being rendered at all, nothing inside it. Do you know why this could be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:comment>//<![CDATA[
<script>        // Loads the video.        var s1 = new SWFObject("player-viral.swf","ply","670","350","9","#ffffff");        s1.addParam("allowfullscreen","true");        s1.addParam("allownetworking","all");        s1.addParam("allowscriptaccess","always");        s1.addParam("flashvars","file=/Portals/0/<xsl:value-of select="MediaUrlFolder"/><xsl:value-of select="ImageUrlFileName"/>&image=/Portals/0///]]><xsl:value-of select="ImageUrlFolder"/><xsl:value-of select="ImageUrlFileName"/><![CDATA[");        s1.write("container");</script>
//]]></xsl:comment>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, seems 2 be a good idea. In my case, I found out the software I was using blocked javascripts for security purposes.